React webiste showing blank screen with error on the console the server responded with a status of 404 ()
I have deployed my react wesite portfolio on Github and it is showing a blank screen with error in console ->Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
and link to the repository/site is https://elochimombe.github.io/portfolio/
and the link to the githup is https://github.com/EloChimombe
and the name of repository is portfolio
I tried some solutions but I dont where am I failing

Where do you think it is going to find the react module?  Are you sure this is intended to run in the browser, and not in node.js?

main.jsx is not loading in your html.

Since your Repo's name is portfolio, change the base name to /portfolio/ in the vite.config.js and redeploy it.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
// import viteCompression from 'vite-plugin-compression';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    base: '/portfolio/',
    plugins: [
      react(),
      // viteCompression()
    ],
    assetsInclude: ['**/*.jpg', '**/*.png', '**/*.svg', '**/*.gif'],
  }
});

